# jQuery Causing Invisible Bullets in IE8 Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I've created a simple quiz that i'm using in Plone (that's why I use 'jQuery' instead of '$') and for some reason my javascript code for calculating the score on the fly causes the radio buttons to appear incorrectly in IE 8. By appear incorrectly I mean that after clicking the button the value is calculated correctly, but the bullet doesn't appear to show that the button has been clicked. I'm having a heck of a time trying to correct this. It works perfectly in all other browsers. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/kthomps17/Dtw9K/) is a fiddle with my simple quiz code. In IE8 the radio buttons don't work as expected when the jquery is loaded, but if you comment out all of the javascript the radio buttons work fine.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('input').change(function() {
   // ... [snip] ...
   return false;
});
```

Why are you returning `false`? This usually tells the browser to "cancel" the default behaviour of the event. If anything, I'm surprised that Firefox *doesn't* exhibit this behaviour.

Remove `return false`; unless I'm missing something, your application logic doesn't need it at all.

Comment: I'm not really sure why I put that there, but thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 2):

Ummm... I think a large part of your problem is the incorrect use of the `<input>` element. Inputs are self-closing tags. You can't wrap them around other HTML.

```
<input type="text"><span>HTML here</span></input> <!-- WRONG! -->

<input type="text" /> <span>HTML here</span> <!-- Correct -->
```

**UPDATE:**

Interesting. Just noticed that you're returning `false` from the onchange event. Is there a specific reason for that? Ironically, IE8 may actually be the only one behaving properly. Returning `false` should be taken to mean essentially "cancel what would have been done". In the case of clicks on links, for example, it causes the URL to not be followed. In submitting a form, it will cancel the POST to the server. IE8 may be interpreting it to mean: cancel changing the look of the radio.

Comment: Thanks for finding this obvious error, but unfortunately it is not related to the problem. I thought i had kept the fiddle up to date, but i was mistaken and the code that i'm actually using does have correct input tags yet is suffering from the same problem.

Comment: The update is correct. The radio value change event is "cancelled". It's surprising that Firefox doesn't abide by this. Even IE8 seems to only exhibit the behaviour _some_ of the time.